# Linux kernel does not return TCP packet data to application until the next packet arrives

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

We have a TCP client application that interacts with the TCP server. The protocol is simple request/response with bidirectional pings.

The client in written in C, it calls `read()` from a non-blocking socket file descriptor in an infinite loop.

The problem is that, after some time spent interacting, the client sends a request but doesn't read the response until the next ping from the server. That is, `read()` fails with `errno=EAGAIN` all that time (the kernel behaves as if no new data is available).

In `tcpdump` dumps we see that the response actually came in time (just after we sent the request). And the next packet (ping) came exactly when the kernel did return both the response and the ping to the application.

We have excluded problems in the application (run it under `strace`, it always tries to read new data, but the kernel won't give it).

We're out of ideas now. What could the problem here? How to debug it next?

The OS is Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-67-generic x86_64).

Comment: That is normal because TCP is a stream protocol, not a message protocol like UDP.

Comment: @RonMaupin The delay is several minutes, this is not normal.

Comment: Yes, it is. If you are sending a stream, the TCP buffer will fill more quickly and data will be delivered to the application faster. If you have a large buffer, data can linger there. You seem to want to use TCP as a message protocol, and it is not.

Comment: *"In tcpdump dumps we see that the response actually came in time"* - and did you observe also that an ACK was sent back in time?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich The ping interval is 100 seconds, so we receive data in 0…100 seconds, when the ping packet is sent by the server.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yes, we also see ACKs corresponding to those packets sent in time.

Comment: @RonMaupin Are you saying that lag of 100 seconds is normal for TCP?